# Wikidata SPARQL query has different results in Python

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, wikidata

If I go on https://query.wikidata.org/ and execute this query (made with the Wikidata query builder):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE {
      ?item p:P31 ?statement0.
      ?statement0 (ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q28575.
      ?item p:P17 ?statement1.
      ?statement1 (ps:P17/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q145.
    }
    LIMIT 100
  }
}
```

I get this output:

[image: Wikidata query output]

Essentially, this query is finding counties in the United Kingdom.

Now when I execute this query in Python:

```
# pip install sparqlwrapper
# https://rdflib.github.io/sparqlwrapper/

import sys
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

endpoint_url = "https://query.wikidata.org/sparql"

query = """
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE {
      ?item p:P31 ?statement0.
      ?statement0 (ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q28575.
      ?item p:P17 ?statement1.
      ?statement1 (ps:P17/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q145.
    }
    LIMIT 100
  }
}"""


def get_results(endpoint_url, query):
    user_agent = "WDQS-example Python/%s.%s" % (sys.version_info[0], sys.version_info[1])
    # TODO adjust user agent; see https://w.wiki/CX6
    sparql = SPARQLWrapper(endpoint_url, agent=user_agent)
    sparql.setQuery(query)
    sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
    return sparql.query().convert()


results = get_results(endpoint_url, query)

for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
    print(result)
```

I get this output:

```
{'item': {'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q100166'}, 'itemLabel': {'type': 'literal', 'value': 'Q100166'}}
{'item': {'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q109128'}, 'itemLabel': {'type': 'literal', 'value': 'Q109128'}}
{'item': {'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q156150'}, 'itemLabel': {'type': 'literal', 'value': 'Q156150'}}
{'item': {'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q166803'}, 'itemLabel': {'type': 'literal', 'value': 'Q166803'}}
{'item': {'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q189592'}, 'itemLabel': {'type': 'literal', 'value': 'Q189592'}}
{'item': {'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q190678'}, 'itemLabel': {'type': 'literal', 'value': 'Q190678'}}
```

Rather than getting the name of the county in the itemLabel, I get the Q number. I want the itemLabel to show the names of the counties, as in the screenshot above.

What is going wrong?

Comment: maybe because of the AUTO_LANGUAGE param? What happens if you set it to `en`?

Comment: @UninformedUser That solved it, thanks a lot. I am new to SPARQL and querying Wikidata. Do you mind giving an explanation of why this fixed it?

Comment: I think the `AUTO_LANGUAGE` works only for user interfaces with some language code, the query service would then simply replace it by that inspected language code. Clearly in a browser this works, but for a simple Python request there isn't any hint for the language. Some more details for the label service here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual#Label_service